# Rails Controller method not triggering on an AJAX Post

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to save the values in the database AJAX. Problem is that my controller action is not triggering when the AJAX is executed, and the data being sent is not received. Also, the AJAX call is executing both success and error methods.

My controller 'ServerManagementController' has the action,

```
def read_data         
  @responseArray = JSON.stringify(params[:response])
  @responseArray.length  
  UserServer.makeUserServerRecord #This stores dummy values in the database
end
```

Here is the AJAX,

```
$.ajax(
            {
             url: "/server_management/read_data",
             type: "POST",
             data: JSON.stringify(response),  
             dataType: "json", 
             contentType: 'application/json',
             success: alert("sent"),
             error: alert("failed")
            }
          );
```

And I have defined the route as,

```
resources :server_managements do
  collection do
    post 'read_data'
  end
end
```

I am stuck on this for like two days, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the ajax call return? what is the actual call that is sent?

Comment: I am sending an array as a JSON string, this array has values that will be stored in the database.

Comment: I have tried JSON.stringify(params[:response]) but that does not solve the problem, IMO, the problem is with the route.

Answer (score 0):

in your controller you need render that json as response :

```
def read_data
  @responseArray = params[:response]
  @responseArray.length  
  if UserServer.makeUserServerRecord
    render json: {status: "ok"}
  else
    render json: {status: "false"}
  end
end
```

Ajax should be something like this :

```
type: 'POST',
  datatype: 'json',
  url: '/server_managements/read_data/',
  success: function(status){
    if (status.success === true) {
      alert("sent");
    }else{
      alert("failed");
    }
   }
```

Let me know is that ok .

Comment: That does not work. The action is not triggering. Are you sure I have defined the route correctly?

Comment: I have used the singular term in the path and the route, and it works.

Comment: @zauzaj: Route: `resources :zone_management do
    collection do
      post 'read'
      post 'updategrid'
    end
 end'`
      

Controller name: **server_management_controller**

AJAX path: **/server_management/read/** #Yes I changed the action name

Answer (score 0):

If the action is not being called, perhaps you'd benefit from the following:

--

**Backend**

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :server_management do
  collection do
    post :read_data #-> domain.com/server_management/read_data
  end
end
```

I think one of your main issues was (is) that you're not sending the correct data through to your `ServerManagementController`, regardless of whether you have any other issues with the controller itself

```
#app/controllers/server_management_controller.rb
Class ServerManagementController < ApplicationController
   def read_data
      ...
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: "Response".to_json }
      end
   end
end
```

This allows you to define the response from your JSON request, giving you the ability to define the files you need for it to run. Handling the status / success will be dependent on your supporting `UserServer` code

--

**Ajax**

The ajax `error` function is only called when your ajax request does not hit the controller / endpoint (`404` etc). As according to `zauzaj`, you'll want to do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/server_management/read_data",
  type: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify(response),  
  dataType: "json", 
  success: function(data) {
    alert("sent");
  },
  error: function(data) {
    alert("failed")
  }
});
```

I, too, used to think the Ajax error callback happened when there was a genuine issue. Not so - it's *only* when the request does not reach the endpoint you specify, preventing it from being able to actually fire at all.

If you want to handle any exceptions with Ajax, you need to make the determination in your `success` callback; at least from my experience.

Comment: The issue was that the JSON packet being sent was not of the correct format, so the method 'JSON.stringify(response)' wasn't working. I had to create my own JSON for it to work.

Also, since the action does not render anything, I added 'render :nothing => true' in the end of the read_data action.

And thanks for the advice on the success callback, it did work.